# Convert dynamic sql to key-value pairs in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

From within a stored procedure, I have a need to convert a dynamic SQL statement stored in a variable @sql into a temporary table of essentially key-value pairs - knowing nothing more about the content of @sql than that it is a select statement, call to a table-valued function, or some other sql that will return a result set.  In other words, the schema of that select is not pre-defined or known at the time the stored procedure is called.

So, essentially, I need to be able to transform

```
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

where the ad hoc query provided could be something like

```
select foo_varchar, bar_int, alice_bit from [some_table] with (nolock)
```

into a temporary table of the form (where field_value is the varchar representation of whatever value):

```
row_num  field_name   field_value
-------  ----------   --------------
1        foo_varchar  'a funny name'
1        bar_int      '17'
1        alice_bit    '1'
2        foo_varchar  'another name'
2        bar_int      '76'
2        alice_bit    '0'
...
```

Thus far, I have been unable to devise a way to do this.  But before I give up and try a different approach, I thought I'd ask my fellow SO'ers...

Comment: I would, personally, suggest you rethink your design. This will be, in truth, an absolute nightmare to maintain and I don't doubt that any attempts would be subject to guesswork, good faith, and luck more than anything.

Comment: Stop splattering [nolock everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Good article!  I'll try to be more conscientious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requested XML Version or **[dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d34667c3d4d938063bc421818435d735)**

```
Select A.row_num
      ,C.*
 From  (
     Select *,row_num = row_number() over ( order by (select null))
      From  YourTable
       ) A
 Cross Apply ( values ((Select A.* for XML RAW,Type)) )B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select field_name  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
                      ,field_value  = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                 From XMLData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
                 Where xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')  not in ('row_num')
             ) C
```

**Fully Dynamic Version**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = 'Select foo_varchar,bar_int,alice_bit from YourTable '

-- Augment Original SQL
Set @SQL = '
Select A.row_num
      ,C.*
 From  (
         Select *,row_num = row_number() over ( order by (select null))
          From  ('+@SQL+') src
       ) A
 Cross Apply ( values ((Select A.* for XML RAW,Type)) )B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select field_name  = xAttr.value(''local-name(.)'', ''varchar(100)'')
                      ,field_value  = xAttr.value(''.'',''varchar(max)'')
                 From XMLData.nodes(''//@*'') xNode(xAttr)
                 Where xAttr.value(''local-name(.)'', ''varchar(100)'')  not in (''row_num'')
             ) C

'
Exec(@SQL)
```

**EDIT - If Open to a Table-Valued Function**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = 'Select foo_varchar,bar_int,alice_bit from YourTable '

-- Augment Original SQL
Set @SQL = '
Select A.row_num
      ,B.*
 From  (
         Select *,row_num = row_number() over ( order by (select null))
          From  ('+@SQL+') src
       ) A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-XML-UnPivot-Row]((Select A.* for XML RAW)) B
 Where Item<>''row_num''
'
Exec(@SQL)
```

**The Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-XML-UnPivot-Row](@XML xml)
Returns Table 
As
Return ( 
        Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
              ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
         From  @XML.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
)
```

Comment: You sir are a scholar and a gentleman!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

No need for Dynamic SQL.  You can dynamically unpivot your data with a bit of JSON

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f17bbe8427359e51edc74b362e8b736e)**

```
Select A.row_num
      ,B.*
 From  (
         Select *,row_num = row_number() over ( order by (select null))
          From  YourTable
       ) A
 Cross Apply (
                Select field_name  = [Key]
                      ,field_value = [Value]
                 From OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES  ) ) 
                 Where [Key] not in ('row_num')
             ) B
```

**Notes:**

- The `,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES` is optional
- The `order by (select null)` is a generic place holder.  Use proper sequence if available.
- The JSON approach requires 2016+.  There is a similar XML version for <2016

**UPDATE - For Fully Dynamic Option**

```
-- Your ORIGINAL SQL
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = 'Select foo_varchar,bar_int,alice_bit from YourTable '

-- Here we Augment the Original SQL
-- You may want to consider a scalar-valued function where you pass `@SQL`
Set @SQL = '
Select A.row_num
      ,B.*
 From  (
         Select *,row_num = row_number() over ( order by (select null))
          From  ('+@SQL+') src
       ) A
 Cross Apply (
                Select field_name  = [Key]
                      ,field_value = [Value]
                 From OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES  ) ) 
                 Where [Key] not in (''row_num'')
             ) B
'
Exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: You would need to, effectively, inject your stored statement into the above query, @GeorgeMenoutis , so create a new dynamic statement from your existing "dynamic" one.

Comment: Would you mind terribly much posting an XML version?  I am unfortunately stuck with an existing DB using a 120 compatibility level.  I am very intrigued by this post however.

Comment: @Mitselplik I added a second answer to support the XML approach

Comment: @Mitselplik Fair warning.  The xml versions does NOT like columns beginning with numbers or special characters.   Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=3b1fe24969316ca0f30bb96105cabe4b  Notice I renamed [foo_varchar] to [200foo_varchar]  (notice the leading 200)